# Bracket code section in use strict / no strict?

Tags: perl, strict

I inherited some perl code that of course doesn't use either strict or warnings, and I keep using uninitialized variables and the like.

I'd like to bracket the sections of code that I'm modifying like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

... my code changes and additions ...

no strict;
no warnings;
```

And that seems to work, but I'm having issues deciphering what [the perldoc on use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) means when it says these are compiler directives that import into the current "block scope."   Does that mean that any scope can have a `use strict` unpaired with a `no strict`?  Is the `no strict` at the tail of the global scope essentially undoing the meaning of `use strict` earlier in the same scope?

Comment: I'll confirm this is a good idea to *temporarily* work with existing code. Even better would be to put your additions into functions in a separate library file.  You'll eventually want to bring it all under strict.

Comment: Someone who doesn't `use strict` of course doesn't also allow easy code encapsulation... I have to add to their eleventytwo global hashtables, you see...

Comment: Yes, it's frustrating, but it doesn't prevent you from using library subroutines.  You can refer to their globals with `%main::blah` (assuming it's in package main).  Even better, pass their globals you need to modify into your subroutines by reference: `some_new_sub(\%blah)`.  It will prevent their global mess from infecting new code.  This will be messy at first, but it will give you a better idea of what code needs what data.  Through all this, the Extract Method pattern will be your strongest tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"block scope" means both `use strict;` and `no strict;` have effect from where they are to the end of the innermost enclosing block, so no, a later `no strict` doesn't undo an earlier `use strict`.  It just changes it for the innermost scope from that point in the code on.  So:

```
{
    use strict;
    # strict in effect
    {
        # strict still in effect
        no strict;
        # strict not in effect
    }
    # strict in effect
    no strict;
    # strict not in effect
    use strict;
    # strict in effect
}
```

Comment: Good illustration, thanks.  I had two concerns:  1.) There are few examples of people using `no strict` for this, to bracket changes to unstrict code.  2.) I was worried there was a sort of 2-pass interpretation of scope that might make things not work like illustrated, so the confirmation is good.

Comment: "Block scope" is also referred to as "lexical scope".  It's important to note that lexical scope does *not* enter subroutine calls.  "Lexical" as in "what you read on the page".  `no strict` in small blocks is often used on the rare occasions when you want to use symbolic references.  A common use is creating subroutines on the fly.  `{ no strict 'refs'; *{$sub_name} = sub { ... } }`.

Comment: as opposed to "dynamic scope" which does enter subroutine calls